# Print the output of imported functions in Tkinter widget with Python

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter

My GUI app has two files: `gui.py` that contains all the Tkinter objects and `controller.py` contains the logic. The logic is one main function `def automation():` that nests several other functions. The app is very simple it's only one button that calls `automation()`.

I would like to add the print statements and errors that appear in the terminal in the GUI widget so that the user can see what's going on. I can't find a way to do that for imported modules.

gui.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from controller import automation    

root = tk.Tk()
frame_button = tk.Frame(root)
button = Button(frame_button, text="Ship", command=lambda:automation())
lower_frame = tk.Frame(root)
terminal = tk.Label(lower_frame)

frame_button.place()
button.place()
lower_frame.place()
terminal.place()
```

controller.py

```
def automation():
  def folder_cleaner():
    print('Folders cleaned')

  def dispatch():
    print('Dispatch done')

  def ship():
    print('Shipment successful')

  def process():
    folder_cleaner()
    dispatch()
    ship()

  process()
```

This is very simplified but each function has many different kinds of outputs. How can I redirect all of them to `gui.py` and inside the `terminal widget`?

Comment: this: `command=lambda:automation()` can be shortened to this: `command=automation`

Answer (score 0):

To show the output in the UI, I've added an `output` function in gui.py. So the function can be used in controller.py, I've added a parameter `outputFunc` when calling `automation`. This can then be used instead of print to display the strings in the UI.
gui.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from controller import automation    

def output(text):
    terminal.insert("end", text + "\n")

root = tk.Tk()
frame_button = tk.Frame(root)

button = Button(frame_button, text="Ship", command=lambda:automation(output))
lower_frame = tk.Frame(root)
#Changed to text widget as it is more ideal for this purpose
terminal = tk.Text(lower_frame)

#Changed place to pack so widgets actually display
frame_button.pack()
button.pack()
lower_frame.pack()
terminal.pack()
```

controller.py

```
def automation(outputFunc):
  def folder_cleaner():
    outputFunc('Folders cleaned')

  def dispatch():
    outputFunc('Dispatch done')

  def ship():
    outputFunc('Shipment successful')

  def process():
    folder_cleaner()
    dispatch()
    ship()

  process()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to Your issue (this works especially well if Your automation runs in a loop or basically is not as fast, it will make sure to update when any change happens):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Frame
from _thread import start_new_thread
from time import sleep


values = {'random_values': []}


def automation():
    for i in range(10):
        values['random_values'].append(i)
        sleep(3)


def watch_values():
    compare = None
    while True:
        value = str(values['random_values'])
        if compare != value:
            label.config(text=values['random_values'])
            compare = value


root = Tk()

Button(root, text='start', command=lambda: start_new_thread(automation, ())).pack()

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
start_new_thread(watch_values, ())

root.mainloop()
```

So basically first it starts a thread that watches the `values` dictionary (it is important for it to interact with tkinter only when there are changes tho because otherwise it will cause issues with tkinter GUI so that is why there is `compare`).

Whenever there is a change in that particular variable it sets the text of the label as that variable (variable being `values['random_values']`).

Then there is the automation function. I suggest that You put everything it returns in a dictionary that will be watched by the other thread. You also need to thread Your automation function so that it can work in parallel. (And You can obviously import that function from another file, just add it to the threads, also it may seem weird but those empty tuples there are necessary since that is an argument (in those tuples it is also possible to put the function argument if You have those but in this case there are none))

And You only need one watcher function, just add more compares and checks to that loop and so on (mentioned in case You wanted to create such a function for every key in the dictionary which is completely unnecessary)